# Pig Script working on 0.12.0 but not on 0.11.1

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have written this pig script which runs perfectly on version 0.12.0 but I can't get it working on 0.11.1
I am not able to identify what's really missing.

```
data = LOAD '<file_name>' USING PigStorage(',') AS 
(Year,Month:int,DayofMonth,DayOfWeek,DepTime,CRSDepTime,ArrTime,CRSArrTime,UniqueCarrier,
    FlightNum,TailNum,ActualElapsedTime,CRSElapsedTime,AirTime,ArrDelay:int,DepDelay,Origin,
    Dest,Distance,TaxiIn,TaxiOut,Cancelled,CancellationCode,Diverted,CarrierDelay,
    WeatherDelay,NASDelay,SecurityDelay,LateAircraftDelay);
A = FILTER data BY (ArrDelay > 0);
X = GROUP A BY (Dest, Year, 
        (
            Case
                when Month>2 AND Month<6 THEN 'SPRING'
                when Month>5 AND Month<9 THEN 'SUMMER'
                when Month>8 AND Month<12 THEN 'FALL'
                when Month==12 OR (Month<3 AND Month>0) THEN 'WINTER'
            END
        )
    );
Y = FOREACH X GENERATE group.Dest, group.Year, group.$2, SUM(A.ArrDelay);
STORE Y INTO 'myoutput';
```

Here's the exception which is given while running the script.

```
Pig Stack Trace
---------------
ERROR 1200: <file DelayBySeasonPerYear.pig, line 7, column 16>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'Dest'

org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. <file DelayBySeasonPerYear.pig, line 7, column 16>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'Dest'
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1607)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1546)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:516)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:991)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:412)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:194)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:170)
    at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.exec(Grunt.java:84)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:604)
    at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:160)
Caused by: Failed to parse: <file DelayBySeasonPerYear.pig, line 7, column 16>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'Dest'
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:235)
    at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:177)
    at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.parseQuery(PigServer.java:1599)
    ... 14 more
```

Comment: A tip, `Y` can be just `Y = FOREACH X GENERATE FLATTEN(group), SUM(A.ArrDelay);`.  When you use `FLATTEN` on a tuple it does the same thing as generating each element separately (like you have done).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` was only recently implemented in version 0.12. It is not available in 0.11.

See:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-3268 (notice fix version 0.12)
- http://hortonworks.com/blog/announcing-apache-pig-0-12/ (blog post about new features in 0.12, one of which is `CASE`)

---

Suggested work around:

Write a [UDF](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/udf.html) that takes in a Month value and then returns a `chararray` with the written out season. Then, use this UDF in a `FOREACH` statement after your FILTER.

```
...
A = FILTER data BY (ArrDelay > 0);
A = FOREACH A GENERATE MySeasonUDF(Month) as Season, Dest, Year, ArrDelay;
X = GROUP A BY (Dest, Year, Season);
...
```

Comment: I see can you please suggest any work around what can I use instead of Case to achieve the same functionality

Comment: @DonaldMiner Isn't the UDF usable in the `GROUP`? Something like `X = GROUP A BY (Dest, Year, MySeasonUDF(Month)) ;` should prevent an additional map job, unless pig automatically optimizes this.

Comment: @mr2ert pig automatically folds multiple foreach/filter in a row into a single map (or reduce if after the group). But, I think you are right that you can just do it in the group. Simpler syntactically for sure.